# Windows Phone app profiling results

Tags: windows-phone, profiling

I've been doing performance profiling of my Windows Phone application. I tested the average memory usage of my application (via ALT + F1). I get an average memory usage of 17MB but i don't have any clue if this result is good or bad? On what it depends?

Comment: *It depends*.  If memory isn't an issue at all, 17MB is probably fine.  I would try creating a similar app (i.e. if you used one of the project templates) and without adding all the stuff *your* app does, see how much memory it takes up.  then you have a baseline to compare to.